# Moment.js: Why this conversion Date -> Unix is giving me 5:00:00 instead of 0:00:00?

Tags: jquery, date, momentjs

I have this jquery/moment.js code:

```
var check_in_proper = '15-09-2020';
var ts = moment(check_in_proper, "DD/MM/YYYY").valueOf()/1000;
alert(ts);
```

This is giving me this timestamp: 1600146000, which is Tuesday, 15 September 2020 **5:00:00**.
But I expected to get 1600128000, which is Tuesday, 15 September 2020 0:00:00.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [utc()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) function to get correct time and date and instead of using `valueOf` you can also use [unix()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/) function of `momentJS`

**Live Demo:**

```js
var check_in_proper = '15-09-2020'; //date
var ts = moment.utc(check_in_proper, "DD/MM/YYYY").unix() //unix
var formattedDate = moment.unix(ts).utc().format("dddd, D MMMM YYYY, HH:mm:ss");
console.log(ts); //1600128000
console.log(formattedDate); //Tuesday, 15 September 2020, 00:00:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```